# "Actually" as a sentence-starter of speech filler

Tags: mandarin, spoken

When casually speaking English I use the word "actually" a lot at the beginning of a sentance, or as part of the flow of my speech. e.g.

> Actually, next semester doesn't start for a month.
>
> Actually, I don't have any siblings.

I would like to be able to continue this speech habit in Mandarin Chinese, I have been using 事实上 (shìshíshàng), but from my listeners' reactions I am not sure if this is really the same.

What is the closest equivalent expression?

Comment: Starting your sentences with "actually" can be an effective way to annoy people.

Comment: mandarin chinese is the perfect opportunity for new beginnings.

Comment: @NullUserException Actually, not always. ... :P ahah sorry, I couldn't help it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"其实" or "其实呢" is more similar to what you wanted, casually. E.g.

> 其实我没有兄弟姐妹.

"事实上" is not wrong, but it is literally "in fact" or "as a matter of fact".

Comment: 实际上... Will be ok too

Comment: @AntiGameZ That's right. At first, I thought "实际上" is more similar to "事实上" without thinking too much. Now I get it...

Answer (score 6):

Following on from Flake, I also often hear people saying 那么 (那) or just as a way to begin sentences, or 那个 when stopping to think in mid sentences. Is that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: sort of.. but I was after something conveying the sense that I am attempting to clarify the topic under discussion

Comment: @trideceth12  Do you want to imply that others in the conversation need you to clear it up for them?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty yeah

Answer (score 4):

An addition to other great answers:

反正 can be used as "actually" too sometimes.

Example:

> - 谢谢你过来帮我 (*Thanks for coming over to help me*)
>     <sub>Xièxie nǐ guò lái bāng wǒ</sub>
> - 反正我刚好在这边附近而已 (*Actually, I happened to be just around the corner*)
>     <sub>fǎn zhèng wǒ gāng hăo zài zhè biān fù jìn ér yǐ</sub>

Comment: I corrected the examples but they need to be peer-reviewed first. I wrote a _ (underscore) where I didn't know the pinyin. Who knows it, feel free to add it and correct possible mistakes! :)